# AndAlso для двух параметров

Tags: c#, expressions

Пытаюсь собрать Expression> из двух двух через AndAlso

```
internal static Expression<Func<Contact, PersonIdentity, bool>> Construct(ContactMatchOptions options)
{
    Expression<Func<Contact, PersonIdentity, bool>> predicate =
        (a, b) => StringDupe(a.Firstname, b.FirstName) &&
                  StringDupe(a.Lastname, b.LastName) &&
                  StringDupe(a.Middlename, b.MiddleName);

    if (options == ContactMatchOptions.SimpleMatch)
        return predicate;

    if (options == ContactMatchOptions.WithEmail)
    {
        Expression<Func<Contact, PersonIdentity, bool>> exprWithEmail = (a, b) => WithEmail(a, b);
        predicate.AndAlso(exprWithEmail);
    }

    return predicate;
}
```

Ранее я такое делал только для случая одной переменной:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AndAlso<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
{
    var param = expr1.Parameters[0];

    if (ReferenceEquals(param, expr2.Parameters[0]))
    {
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, expr2.Body), param);
    }

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, Expression.Invoke(expr2, param)), param);
}
```

Наивная попытка обобщить:

```
public static Expression<Func<T1, T2, bool>> AndAlso<T1, T2>(this Expression<Func<T1, T2, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<T1, T2, bool>> expr2)
{
    var param = expr1.Parameters[0];

    if (ReferenceEquals(param, expr2.Parameters[0]))
    {
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, T2, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, expr2.Body), param);
    }

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, T2, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, Expression.Invoke(expr2, param)), param);
}
```

компилируется но выдаёт исключение в рантайме:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : Неверное количество аргументов, заданных для лямбда-вызова
   в System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateArgumentCount(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, Int32 count, ParameterInfo[] pis)
   в System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateArgumentTypes(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, ReadOnlyCollection`1& arguments)
   в System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Invoke(Expression expression, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
   в StandardSnippets.Extensions.QueryBuilder.AndAlsoExtension.AndAlso[T1,T2](Expression`1 expr1, Expression`1 expr2)
```

Какие параметры (`expr1.Parameters[0]` (Contact) и `expr1.Parameters[1]` (PersonIdentity)) и куда компилятор ожидает?

Мне нужно получить такое дерево выражений в итоге:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Постепенно начал дампить параметры и подбирать под нужную структуру, компилируется, но дерево выглядит иначе:

```
public static Expression<Func<T1, T2, bool>> AndAlso<T1, T2>(this Expression<Func<T1, T2, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<T1, T2, bool>> expr2)
{
    var param1 = expr1.Parameters[0];
    //param1.Dump();

    var param2 = expr1.Parameters[1];
    //param2.Dump();

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, T2, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, expr2.Body), param1, param2);
}
```

Comment: а в чем проблема? в первом случае вы пытаетесь создать лямбку с двумя параметрами, но передаете один, а во втором все верно. PS. тут `predicate.AndAlso(exprWithEmail)` скорее всего дождно быть `predicate = predicate.AndAlso(exprWithEmail)` или `return predicate.AndAlso(exprWithEmail)`

Comment: я точно помню, что отвечал на подобный вопрос. а найти не могу :( Можешь в удаленных поискать?

Comment: @Grundy В удалённых точно нет, я просмотрел [все 26](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A186999+deleted%3Ayes) ответов.

Comment: @AK, похоже про вот это я помнил :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/29894371/2881286

Answer (score 1):

Предыдущая версия ответа не работала, всё-таки надо было использовать замену переменных:

```
public static Expression<Func<T1, T2, bool>> AndAlso<T1, T2>(this Expression<Func<T1, T2, bool>> left, Expression<Func<T1, T2, bool>> right)
{
    var replaced = right.Body
                        .ReplaceParameter(right.Parameters[0], left.Parameters[0])
                        .ReplaceParameter(right.Parameters[1], left.Parameters[1]);

    var body = Expression.AndAlso(left.Body, replaced);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, T2, bool>>(body, left.Parameters);
}
```

Использовал ParameterReplacer отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36651409/5752652